BizTalk changes after MSDTC logging file size change
We have a clustered environment of two BizTalk servers and two SQL servers. We are in process of changing the MSDTC log file size to a definite size of 50 MB so that it can handle maximum concurrent transactions. So if we change the file size is there anything we have to do on the BizTalk end? I mean do we have to restart the host instances etc?

According to this article, you should stop all host instances before the change.  https://vikas15bhardwaj.wordpress.com/2014/06/29/msdtc-log-full-error-resolution-on-biztalk-server/

We did the change and restarted the host instances after that. Its been weeks and no issues have occurred till date.
